# Google Sheets: Exclude the current date row from protection

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I have a table in Google Sheets in the format:

A B C

Day  Date  inventory  demand

Day2 Date2 inventory demand

etc.

Others are required to fill in inventory and demand every day. However, they should only fill out demand and inventory of the current day. They are also not allowed to change previous data or in advance fill in future days inventory and demand.
Therefore, I want to protect the whole sheet from being edited by others, except the row with the current date. For example today (23.09) they should be able to edit the row where B is 23.09.2019 and nothing else.

Could somebody please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The workflow can be as following

- Loop through all sheet rows comparing the date in column B against today
- Return the row index with today's date
- Remove all existing sheet protections
- Create a [protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) that protects the whole sheet with exception of the row containing today's date with `setUnprotectedRanges`

**Sample:**

```
function myFunction() {
 var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
 var range=sheet.getDataRange();
 var values=range.getValues();
 var today=new Date();
 today.setHours(0);
 today.setMinutes(0);
 today.setSeconds(0);
 today.setMilliseconds(0);
 var todayMs=today.getTime();
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    var date=values[i][1];
    var dateMs=date.getTime();
    if(dateMs==todayMs){
      var row=i+1;
      break;
    }
  }  
  var protections=sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET); 
 for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  var protection = protections[i];
  if (protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
   } 
 } 
 var myProtection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range'); 
 var rangeToday=sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
 myProtection.setUnprotectedRanges([rangeToday]);
 myProtection.removeEditors(myProtection.getEditors());
}
```

> Note: This code exits the loop after finding the first row containing
>   today's date. Should you have several rows with the same date, you
>   need to modify the code by converting `row` into an array that can
>   contain various entries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am not sure if it works. I put your code into the macros, however if I access the file with another profile the file can still be edited. Sorry I am new to GoogleSheets, do I have to add more? For example if I make the file accessible to someone with a link and he can edit, he can edit everything. Sorry I should have specified this part more.

Comment: May I ask you either you ran the macro after creating it?  Also, if you want to run the function e.g. every day, instead of running the code/macro manually, you can set up an installable time-based trigger, see here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atHour(Integer)

Comment: I copied your code opened Script Editor and pasted your code and pressed the play button afterwards. I got now the error TypeError: Funktion getTime in Objekt not found (line 28, file "Code"). However if I create a link I can still edit everything. Maybe my logic of sharing is wrong?

Comment: This error means that the date of today is not contained in the spreadsheet. The problem might originate from the spreadsheet not recognizing your (German) formatting as valid date formatting.  In this case you need to adjust your date formatting according to your Spreadsheet settings

Comment: Again thank you! I will check tomorrow more precisely if this works. However the format is right now the universal DD.MM.YYYY. I tried to change it to the American MM/DD/YYYY and it still did not work. The first column A has the german days Montag, Tuesday etc, however this should not be a problem as column B contains enough information. Further it is defined by A2=B2.

Comment: The problem is that your first date containing row is row 6, so the rows before give your an error. Just change the loop range from `for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)` to `for(var i=5;i<values.length;i++)` to fix the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you are happy with the answer, please consider accepting it.